# Responsive nav bar pushes down content in Safari/iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a site here: http://teamcherry.com.au/

The site uses a responsive nav plugin, so when viewport is narrow enough the nav is hidden behind a Menu button. When the menu button is pressed, the nav appears. In Firefox and Chrome, the nav appears over the top of content, which is the desired effect in this case. In Safari and mobile Safari however, opening the nav up pushes content down, which isn't what I want.

I've been trying to fix the issue by applying position: absolute to various elements but the layout keeps breaking. I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious here! Anyone able to help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float: right` from your nav style.